# I wanna use model attribute in view Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel, rails-models

I am trying to use attribute value in model but its not working..
I have three models:

***models/resident.rb***

```
class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hostel
  has_one :user,dependent: :delete
end
```

***models/user.rb***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to:resident
end
```

***models/hostel.rb***

```
class Hostel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :residents
  has_one :rate_card,dependent: :delete
end
```

**Schema**

*Resident*

```
create_table "residents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "room_number"
    t.string   "roll_number"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "hostel_id"
  end
```

*User*

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "roll_number"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    t.integer  "resident_id"
  end
```

*Hostel*

```
create_table "hostels", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "hostel"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Now i want to use the hostel attribute value in ***users/show.html.erb***
I am able to do this :

```
<%if @user.resident.roll_number=="101303110"%>
```

if the roll number is present then returning **true**..
but if is use :

```
<%if @user.resident.hostel=="J"%>
```

and if J is a hostel present in Hostel model then it is returning  **false**.

But  when we put`<%@user.resident.hostel%>` in show.html.erb then it is showing value J. 
How should I use related models attributes in each other view?

Comment: "wanna"? "i"? If you look at other questions and answers you'll find relatively few instances of intentionally-incorrect spelling and grammar. Please save that for texting.

Comment: -_- I m here for coding help,not for learning english !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your associations, `@user.resident.hostel` would load a hostel. But you want to compare the `hostel` string on the `hostel`. Therefore your comparison should be:

```
<% if @user.resident.hostel.hostel == 'J' %>
```

Explanation:

```
@user                         # returns your a user

@user.resident                # follows `belongs_to :resident` and 
                              # returns a resident

@user.resident.hostel         # follows `belongs_to :hostel` on the resident and
                              # returns a hostel

@user.resident.hostel.hostel  # returns the value store in the `hostel`
                              # column of that `hostel`
```

Btw. I would argue that chaining calls like that violates the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). But it is hard to suggest any alternative without having more insights into your app.

Comment: Can u explain how its working ? 
And yes it is working :D